# Why is 8080 port easy to be attacked?

Tags: security

I learnt from [some websites](http://baike.baidu.com/view/416676.htm) (Sorry, it's Chinese website.) that 8080 port is easy to be attacked, but they don't give the reason why it is easy to be attacked by Trojan virus, such as Brown Orifice(BrO), RemoConChubo, and RingZero.

I just want to know some more specific reasons why it is easy to be attacked. Is it particularly easy to be attacked, or, other ports are also easy to be attacked not only 8080 port?

Comment: Please give me a reason why you downvote. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://security.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I am new to stackoverflow. I'd love to cooperate with platform maintenance work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A port is just a designation, it does not affect how attackable an application is. If port 8080 is easier to attack than port 1332 it simply means the application running on port 8080 is easier to attack than the application running on port 1332.

Port 8080 is a common alternate port for HTTP so scripts that attack HTTP will likely target that port along with port 80. You might say a web server running on port 8080 is more *likely* to be attacked than a web server running on port 1332.

Comment: Yes, it's web server running on port 8080 is more likely to be attacked. I saw this in another website. I don't know whether it is true or why it is more likely to be attacked. Is it because of this reason that many websites' don't have **www** before their addresses?

Comment: Its more likely to be attacked because you will find it on a lot of servers. Its just more common than other port numbers for a web server. As for www check this question: http://superuser.com/questions/142001/why-do-some-websites-have-just-http-in-url-address-without-www/142005